# How can I get a list of the "coefficients" of Quaternion[1, 2, 3, 4]?

Tags: quaternions

I want to input: `Quaternion[1, 2, 3, 4]` to get a list: `{1,2,3,4}`.

Comment: You could always just `List @@ q` (see `Apply`).  But then you can do almost anything with `q = Quaternion[1,2,3,4]` that you can do with `{1,2,3,4}`.  For example, you can extract the 2nd part as `q[[2]]`, etc.  I am a bit tempted to vote to close as simple mistake.  If you disagree, can you elaborate?

Comment: @Szabolics  Thank you.  I was not aware that q[[2]] would extract the 2nd part. Now I am even more embarrassed to ask this question:  I have: 7 + 5 Sqrt[2]  but I want the  list: {7,5}.

Comment: This second question is not a simple one.  The difficulty is deciding (i..e precisely defining) *why* the second term should be `5` and not `5 Sqrt[2]` or something else.  If we treat `Sqrt[2]` as special, we can use `CoefficientList[7 + 5 Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2]]`.

Comment: Thank you very much Szabolics.  I use CoefficientList quite often.  I don't know why I did not think to try it here.